# Print a sequence on one line in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, sequence

I've managed to get the sequencing correct, however I'm unsure how to have it print on the same line. I've got this:

```
n = input ("Enter the start number: ")
i = n+7

if n>-6 and n<93:
    while (i > n):
        print n
        n = n+1
```

and have tried this:

```
n = input ("Enter the start number: ")
i = n+7

if n>-6 and n<93:
    while (i > n):
        print (n, end=" ")
        n = n+1
```

Comment: Once you cast your input to `int` this code works. What exactly is not working to your expectations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by your first (working) code, you are probably using Python 2. To use `print(n, end=" ")` you first have to import the `print` function from Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
if n>-6 and n<93:
    while (i > n):
        print(n, end=" ")
        n = n+1
    print()
```

Alternatively, use the old Python 2 `print` syntax, with a `,` after the statement:

```
if n>-6 and n<93:
    while (i > n):
        print n ,
        n = n+1
    print
```

Or use `" ".join` to join the numbers to one string and print that in one go:

```
print " ".join(str(i) for i in range(n, n+7))
```

Comment: Looks like I needed more help than I thought! Thanks for pointing out I've got the wrong version of Python, that explains so much. Really appreciate the help and advice!

Answer (score 4):

You can use  a range using print as a function and specifying the *sep* arg and unpack with `*`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

n = int(raw_input("Enter the start number: "))
i = n + 7

if -6 < n < 93:
    print(*range(n, i ), sep=" ")
```

Output:

```
Enter the start number: 12 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

You are also using python 2 not python 3 in your first code or your print would cause a syntax error so use raw_input and cast to int.

For python 3 just cast input to int and use the same logic:

```
n = int(input("Enter the start number: "))
i = n + 7

if -6 < n < 93:
    print(*range(n, i ), sep=" ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Padraic!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary string like so:

```
if n>-6 and n<93:
temp = ""
while (i > n):
    temp = temp + str(n) + " "
    n = n+1
print(n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Remuze!

Answer (score -2):

this is coaded in java. the two nested loop are just to print the pattern and stop varialbe is used to terminate loop when we get the required sequence of integer.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PartOfArray {
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int stop =1;   // stop variable 
     /*nested loops to print pattern */    
    for(int i= 1 ; i <= n    ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1 ; j<=i ; j++)
        {
            if (stop > n){ break;} //condation when we print the required no of elements
            System.out.print(i+ " ");
            stop++;
        } 
    } 
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This doesn't seem to answer the OP, as it explicitly asks for help with Python. Please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.